# Adding a new tab to Cost Projection" to retain the details of revision history for each line

Tags: acumatica

> I’m trying to add a tab to Cost Projection
> (PM.30.50.00) that will keep the details of changes for each
> Projection Line in the Details Tab. The Details DAC is
> “PMCostProjectionLine”. I have two problems:
>
> 1)The Revision Log grid
> is read only even though the Add/delete buttons are enabled, when I
> click on Add for example, it inserts a record to the grid, but it is
> read only, and I can not modify the record. I tried to override the
> system behaviour in all of row Selected event but didn’t work.
>
> 2)I would like to push Task and Cost Code from the Details
> (PMCostProjectionLine) grid to Revision Log grid
> (PMCostProjectionRevisionLog) as default by using the Current<> but it
> doesn’t work. I do the same for document header (PMCostProjection) for
> Date and Description fields and it works. It seems the Revision Log
> grid doesn’t read the cache. Both these tabs grids CommitChanges=true
> and Syncposition=true. The funny part is if in the Details tab I click
> on a row and try to add a note for example, then hit the escape and go
> to Revision Log tab and add new record, it reads the correct defaults.
> Here is my GraphExt, DAC and Screen Shot from Cost Projection Screen.

```
using PX.Data; using PX.Data.ReferentialIntegrity.Attributes; using PX.Objects.PM; using System; using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace PX.Objects.CN.ProjectAccounting

{
    public class CostProjectionEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<CostProjectionEntry>
    {
        #region Event Handlers

        protected void PMCostProjectionRevisionLog_RowInserting(PXCache cache, PXRowInsertingEventArgs e)
        {
            var logRow = e.Row as PMCostProjectionRevisionLog;
            var lineRow = Base.Details.Current;
            var docRow = Base.Document.Current;
            if (logRow == null) return;
            if (lineRow == null) return;
            if (docRow == null) return;

            logRow.LineNbr = lineRow.LineNbr;
            logRow.ProjectID = lineRow.ProjectID;
            logRow.RevisionID = docRow.RevisionID;
            logRow.TaskID = lineRow.TaskID;
            logRow.CostCodeID = lineRow.CostCodeID;
            logRow.Date = docRow.Date;
            logRow.Description = docRow.Description;
            logRow.UnitCost = lineRow.Amount;
        }


        protected void PMCostProjectionRevisionLog_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            cache.AllowSelect = true;
            cache.AllowInsert = true;
            cache.AllowUpdate = true;
            cache.AllowDelete = true;
        }


        public PXSelect<PMCostProjectionRevisionLog,
                    Where<PMCostProjectionRevisionLog.projectID, Equal<Current<PMCostProjection.projectID>>,
                        And<PMCostProjectionRevisionLog.date, LessEqual<Current<PMCostProjection.date>>>>> RevisionLog;


        public class PMCostProjectionRevisionLog : IBqlTable
        {
            #region LogNbr
            [PXDBIdentity(IsKey = true)]
            public virtual int? LogNbr { get; set; }
            public abstract class logNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<logNbr> { }
            #endregion

            #region LineNbr
            [PXDBInt]
            [PXForeignReference(typeof(Field<lineNbr>.IsRelatedTo<PMCostProjectionLine.lineNbr>))]
            [PXParent(typeof(Select<PMCostProjectionLine, Where<PMCostProjectionLine.lineNbr, Equal<Current<lineNbr>>>>))]
            public virtual int? LineNbr { get; set; }
            public abstract class lineNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<lineNbr> { }
            #endregion

            #region ProjectID
            [ActiveProjectOrContractBase(Required = true)]
            [PXForeignReference(typeof(Field<projectID>.IsRelatedTo<PMProject.contractID>))]
            [PXDefault(typeof(Current<PMCostProjection.projectID>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Project")]
            public virtual int? ProjectID { get; set; }
            public abstract class projectID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<projectID> { }
            #endregion

            #region RevisionID
            [PXDBString(30, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Revision", Required = true, Enabled = true, Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
            [PXDefault(typeof(Current<PMCostProjection.revisionID>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
            [PXForeignReference(typeof(Field<revisionID>.IsRelatedTo<PMCostProjection.revisionID>))]
            [PXSelector(typeof(Search<PMCostProjection.revisionID, Where<PMCostProjection.projectID, Equal<Current<projectID>>>, OrderBy<Desc<PMCostProjection.revisionID>>>), DescriptionField = typeof(PMCostProjection.description))]
            [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<PMCostProjection.projectID, Equal<projectID>>), "Revision does not exist for the selected project.")]
            public virtual string RevisionID { get; set; }
            public abstract class revisionID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<revisionID> { }
            #endregion

            #region TaskID
            [BaseProjectTaskAttribute(typeof(projectID), AllowInactive = false, AllowCanceled = false, AllowCompleted = false, Required = true)]
            [PXForeignReference(typeof(Field<taskID>.IsRelatedTo<PMTask.taskID>))]
            [PXDefault(typeof(Current<PMCostProjectionLine.taskID>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Task")]
            public virtual int? TaskID { get; set; }
            public abstract class taskID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<taskID> { }
            #endregion

            #region CostCodeID
            [CostCode(null, typeof(taskID), AllowNullValue = false, Required = true)]
            [PXForeignReference(typeof(Field<costCodeID>.IsRelatedTo<PMCostCode.costCodeID>))]
            [PXDefault(typeof(Current<PMCostProjectionLine.costCodeID>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Cost Code")]
            public virtual int? CostCodeID { get; set; }
            public abstract class costCodeID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<costCodeID> { }
            #endregion


            #region Date
            [PXDBDate]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Date", Required = true, Enabled = true)]
            [PXDefault(typeof(Current<PMCostProjection.date>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
            //[PXDefault(typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
            public virtual DateTime? Date { get; set; }
            public abstract class date : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<date> { }
            #endregion

            #region Description
            [PXDBString(500, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Description", Required = true, Enabled = true)]
            [PXDefault(typeof(Current<PMCostProjection.description>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
            public virtual string Description { get; set; }
            public abstract class description : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<description> { }
            #endregion

            #region TotalCost
            [PXDBDecimal()]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Total Cost", Required = true, Enabled = true)]
            [PXDefault(typeof(Current<PMCostProjectionLine.Amount>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
            public virtual Decimal? TotalCost { get; set; }
            public abstract class totalCost : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<totalCost> { }
            #endregion
        }
       #endregion
    } 
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Povgi.png